# write string in file with spaces

Tags: c++, input, line, space, fstream

I've a problem with writing to file. If I write something with spaces, it write each word as a single line. Why?

```
void backstart()
{
    thread t1(backing);
    thread t2(thr2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}

void thr2()
{
    string tmp;
    tmp = "";
    while (tmp != "/exit") 
    {
        cin >> tmp;
        if (tmp != "/exit")
        {
            writefile(tmp);
        }
    }
    runing = false;
}

void writefile(string msg)
{
    ofstream myfile("file.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    myfile << userna + ": " + msg + ",\n";
    myfile.close();
}
```

Thanks
Damon

Comment: `cin >> tmp` will split on spaces. Maybe have a look at [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: THANKS THANKS THANKS! that was realy fast!
Now its running perfect! I didn't know that, because I'm new in c++. ^^

Comment: No problem. I spelled out the read loop in full in my answer. I would recommend you don't try to learn by guesswork and random Googling; you will learn a lot of wrong things and bad practices. Maybe try a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1171191).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider writing it like this:

```
void thr2()
{
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(cin, line)) // this check the read succeeded as well
    {
        if (line=="/exit") break; // stop on "/exit" command
        writefile(line); // write out the line
    }
    running = false; // stop the thread, I guess
}
```

The most important line is

```
while(std::getline(std::cin, line))
```

which reads a whole line at a time into the `std::string` called `line`, *and then checks the state of the stream to make sure the read succeeded*. Read about [`std::getline` here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

**Edit:**

Be very careful (and in fact I suggest just avoiding it) mixing reading with `>>` and `getline`. If you read, for example an `int`, with `>>` it will leave the `'\n'` character at the end of the line, so when you next read with `getline`, you get the *rest* of the line (which is basically nothing), rather than what you probably wanted, which is the *next* line.

If you have just read with `>>` and want to use `getline`, read into the whitespace eater first, like this [`std::cin >> std::ws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws).